# Named doesn't seem to resolve or dig my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone

Here's my named.conf

```
//
// named.caching-nameserver.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat caching-nameserver package to configure the
// ISC BIND named(8) DNS server as a caching only nameserver
// (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - use system-config-bind or an editor
// to create named.conf - edits to this file will be lost on
// caching-nameserver package upgrade.
//
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; any; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";

        forward only;
        forwarders {
        # the following IP addresses are my ISPs DNS Servers. These will be used for looking up
        # hostnames that I don't locally manage, i.e. the REST OF THE INTERNET!
        XXX;     # my ISPs DNS Server #1
        XXX;     # my ISPs DNS Server #2
        };

        // Those options should be used carefully because they disable port
        // randomization
        // query-source    port 53;
        // query-source-v6 port 53;

        allow-query     { localhost; };
        allow-query-cache { localhost; };
        allow-recursion { localhost; };

};
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
view localhost_resolver {
        match-clients      { localhost; };
        match-destinations { localhost; };
        recursion yes;
        include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";

        zone "domain.com" {
                type master;
                file "domain.com.db";
        };
};
include "/etc/rndc.key";
```

Here's my zone file:

```
; Zone file for domain.com
$TTL 14400
domain.com. 86400   IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com.      user.email.com.     (
                                                2013032213 ;Serial Number
                                                86400 ;refresh
                                                7200 ;retry
                                                3600000 ;expire
                                                86400   )

domain.com. 86400   IN      NS      ns1.domain.com.
domain.com. 86400   IN      NS      ns2.domain.com.
ns1.domain.com. 14400 IN    A       xxx
ns2.domain.com. 14400 IN    A       xxx

domain.com. 14400   IN      A       xxx

localhost       14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1

www     14400   IN      CNAME   domain.com.
ftp     14400   IN      A       xxx
```

Bind is running. named-checkconf and named-checkzone return ok. The domain nameservers were also created at the domain registrar. The server also has the IPs in eth0:x...eth0:n. Any ideas what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide the sample output of `dig` including the address of server you're doing `dig` against? And also above mentioned configuration is not serving this zone to internet, in case you're expect it to.

Comment: I am actually wanting to serve internet. I put it inside local_resolvers because named_checkconf asked me to do so. Or is something else what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to reach lucasgomez.com and dig does not return anything, it just hangs.

Comment: a quick whois indicates your nameservers are in-zone (i.e ns1.lucasgomez.com for the lucasgomez.com domain) - do you have a glue record in place with the domain registrar, so it knows where to find your name server?

Comment: @MarkRegensberg Yup, created the nameservers in namecheap too.

Comment: Why did you install the `caching-nameserver` package? This is strictly for local resolvers that aren't serving any zones. This is what the text at the top of `named.conf` is warning you about.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You're totally right, I read over that line for some reason and now remember having read it before, I guess I was distracted. I've used a premade with lots of comments named.conf I found shared online specifically made and change it to that one and configured it to my liking as to what I understand. I'm a bit closer now.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Your observation is spot-on and it's completely possible that this is the problem. I thought that he simply pasted the conf file from somewhere. Lucas, please check how to install the proper package on your distro.

Comment: @zorlem I had followed a guide actually and misguided. This was the problem, I installed caching-nameserver and was using the named.cached-nameserver.conf instead of named.conf hence why I saw my logs weren't changing when I edited something. It took my all day to figure out such a simple mistake. I had also already imporved the config from my initial posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two problems with your configuration:

1. Inside the options you have defined `allow-query { localhost; };`. This instructs your bind DNS server to answer only to localhost and to silently drop all queries from other IP addresses.
2. Your domain is defined only inside your localhost_resolver view. This instructs bind to read and serve the zone's contents only to IP addresses that match the `match-clients` and `match-destinations` options.

Because of these two problems your DNS server(s) are not answering to any requests for the domain:

```
$ host -t ns -v lucasgomez.com. 209.236.113.167
Trying "lucasgomez.com"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I suggest you create an additional view, for serving your public zones. You don't need recursion enabled in there, nor the blackhole zone and it should match and answer queries from any IP address.

```
view "external-in" in {
    match-clients { any; };
    notify yes;
    recursion no;
    additional-from-auth no;
    additional-from-cache no;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    allow-query { any; };

    zone "example.com" in {
        type master;
        file "example.com.db";
        allow-transfer { xferservers; };
    };
};
```

Note that you will need to add an ACL called xferservers with the IP addresses that should be able to initiate AXFR and IXFR zone transfers and adapt the zone snippet for your slave DNS server.

PS. Always check your config before applying it.

Comment: Even though this wasn't exactly the issue causing my problem in particular this config helped me greatly to keep things running smoother! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

zorlem has the best answer based upon the information you have provided, but I also wanted to add that there are several excellent diagnostic web sites that reduce the burden of te many different "dig" commands you have to do to fully diagnose DNS issues.

One that I use a lot is http://dns.squish.net/ which has the following to say regarding your domain:

```
Results

50.0% recvfrom failed from 209.236.113.167; Connection refused - recvfrom(2) at ns1.lucasgomez.com (209.236.113.167)    
50.0% recvfrom failed from 209.236.113.168; Connection refused - recvfrom(2) at ns2.lucasgomez.com (209.236.113.168)
```

So at the very least, your named is not listening for connections on those IPs.

Comment: This probably would have worked better as a comment to zorlem's answer. While you wouldn't have had the space for the example, this really isn't adding anything other than a tool recommendation.

Comment: Oh sorry. I went to do that but the tooltip saying "ask author for clarification about this post" put me off, as I wasn't. Still rather new at this.

Comment: No problem. :) The general rule is "don't reply with an answer unless it provides a different solution". If an existing answer can be built upon, either leave a comment or provide an edit. (unless the answer was lazy and you are doing the work for them)

Comment: Even if the format is wrong... dns.squish.net is super handy and a valid suggestion for later troubleshooting.